# cannot import ipaddr in app engine server

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In the dev_appserver we can import ipaddr successfully,
while when I deploy the codes to app engine server side ,it tells that

```
No module named ipaddr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py", line 700,  in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/app-id/1.2345678/info.py", line 80, in get_ipinfo
    import ipaddr
ImportError: No module named ipaddr
```

But how to import the ipaddr module ipaddr at server side  (path in dev_appserver is /lib/ipaddr/ippaddr/*)?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't add additional modules in Google App Engine. You'll have to use something else.

Comment: You can certainly include extra modules, but they must come along as part of your app, and they can't violate the sandbox policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to use http://code.google.com/p/ipaddr-py/ , then you have to include it (ipaddr.py) as part of your app.